# How to support modularization in Android app with HILT?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, module, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

This interesting [article](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/03/18/modularizationarchitecture/) from Jeroen Mols shows a possible way to modularize an Android app. It basically divides the modules in 3 layers (`App`, `Features` and `Libraries`). `App` communicates directly with `Features` and `Features` can depend on `Libraries`. This means that `App` doesn't interact directly with `Libraries`.

[image]

Now, if I understood correctly HILT documentation, the module that contains the `Application` (which is the App module) and thus it has the HILT entry point (`HiltAndroidApp`) needs to know about all other modules that want to use dependency injection. So for example if I have a library called `libraries:analytics` , I would need my App module to depend on it, so I would be forced to have in my `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation project(":libraries:analytics")
```

which violates the separation and abstraction the whole architecture was trying to achieve.

Is my interpretation correct? If so, what would you do for not breaking the suggested architecture?

Comment: You're correct. You basically have to choose between two options: 1. "Application module depends (sees) on feature modules" -> great HILT integration. 2. "Feature modules depends (sees) on application module" -> not that great HILT integration (you basically end up with vanilla Dagger implementation).

Comment: Thanks @skywall but didn't you mean in option 1 that "Application module depends on LIBRARY modules" ?

Comment: It really depends how your layers are structured and what is your definition of a `library`. Let's image architecture schema mentioned above rotated by 90° -> `Lib -> Feature -> App`. In this case `Lib` layers are basically visible to everyone (if not hidden in `Feature`). But you could also have `App -> Feature -> Lib` or `Lib -> App -> Feature` (I like this one the most). I have written an [article](https://blog.thefuntasty.com/dagger-2-in-android-dynamic-multimodule-project-c90954630615) about Dagger in multimodule project, feel free to take a look.

Comment: I guess you could just completely avoid depending on Dagger from library code.

Comment: Let's assume if my modules are divided in layered architecture like modules :app->:usecase -> :repository -> :localdatastore or remoteservices then i believe app is not at all knowing about datastores so its not possible to integrate HILT in this kind of architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [Hilt Gradle Plugin](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup#hilt-gradle-plugin) and you have transitive dependencies of other modules you can apply below to your **:app/build.gradle** and remove the transitive module(s) dependencies from it.

```
hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = true
}
```

Also refer for more details: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2123#issuecomment-928064317